# Trying to replace a value within a list (via index) with another list in one line of code?

Tags: python, nested, nested-lists

Python: Learning the basics here but I have 2 list and am trying to REPLACE the values of b into a specific index of a. I've tried doing `a.insert(1, b)`, but that shifts the values to the side to insert the list.

Comment: can you clarify your question ? Are you trying to insert a list inside a list, or insert the elements of the list in the other list ?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to insert all values in b into a specifix index in a:

Just do : `a[1] = b`

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that they actually fit

```
a = range(10) // [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
b = range(10, 15) // [10, 11, 12, 13, 14]
```

Now I'll replace the last half of `a` with the values of `b`

```
a[5:5+len(b)] = b // [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14]
```

`5:5+len(b)` produces indexes of 5:10, so 5,6,7,8,9